# multithreaded combining of files (shared memory)

Tags: multithreading, file-io, parallel-processing, hpc, mpi-io

Lets say I have N files in a format like this:

**One File looks like this:**
For each time there is some amount of data with different id

```
- time 1:
      -  data with id: 10
      -  data with id: 13
      -  data with id: 4
- time 2:
      -  data with id: 10
      -  data with id: 77
...etc
```

(for each time the data with ids from 1-1000 are spreaded **some how** (mixed) over these N files)

I would like to combine all these N files so that I have a single file which is ordered :

**Final File:**

```
- time 1:
       -  data with id: 1
       -  data with id: 2
       -  data with id: 3
       -  ...
       -  data with id: 1000

- time 2:
       -  data with id: 1
       -  data with id: 2
       -  data with id: 3
       -  ...
       -  data with id: 1000
...etc
```

The size of data id 1-1000 is approximately 100mb, but I have a lot of times which accounts for up to 50 Gbytes of data.

My solution for this problem would be so far like this to make this as fast as possible:

I use **T  threads** on a supercomputer node (1 computer with e.g. 24-48 cores) (for example). 
I have allocated a **shared memory array to hold all datas with ids 1 - 1000 for one time** (can also be more if I like)

**Procedure:**
Step 1:

- Each thread has some files it opens and owns. Each thread then fills
  in the data of the ids it has in the files into the shared array.

Step 2:

- When all threads have finally processed one time --> Thread 1 writes
  this array in ordered form to the final file.

asdasd

1. I would be very much interested if that is efficient? Is the
   parallel read not sequentialized anyway so it is for no use at all?
   I could compute the final file on a local computer with ultra fast SSD or on a cluster node with network storage
   (Lustres or Panasas Filesystems)
2. Could I use all threads again in
   step 2 to write in parallel to the disk lets say with MPI IO (which 
   supports parallel write by offsets), or how else can that be
   achieved? -> the c++ standart library?

Thanks for any inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach will probably work OK for a moderate amount of data, but you've made one rank the central point of communication here.  That's not going to scale terribly well.

You're on the right track with your part 2: a parallel write using MPI-IO sounds like a good approach to me.  Here's how that might go:

1. Continue to have your T processes read their inputs.
2. I'm going to assume that 'id' is densely allocated.  What I mean is, in this collection of files, can a process know if it sees `data with id: 4` that some other processes have id 1, 2, 3, and 5 ?  If so, then every process knows where it's data has to go.
3. Let's also assume each 'data' is fixed size.  The approach is only a little more complicated if that's not the case.

If you don't know the max ID and the max timesteps, you'd have to do a bit of communication (MPI_Allreduce with MPI_MAX as the operation) to find that.

With these preliminaries,  you can set an MPI-IO "file view", probably using `MPI_Type_indexed`

On rank 0, this gets a bit more complicated because you need to add to your list of data the timestep markers.  Or, you can define a file format with an index of timesteps, and store that index in a header or footer.

The code would look roughly like this:

```
for(i=0; i<nitems; i++)
    datalen[i] = sizeof(item);
    offsets[i] = sizeof(item)*index_of_item;
}
MPI_Type_create_indexed(nitems, datalen, offsets, MPI_BYTE, &filetype);
MPI_File_set_view(fh, 0, MPI_BYTE, filetype, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL);
MPI_File_write_all(fh, buffer, nitems*sizeof(item), MPI_BYTE, &status);
```

The _all bit here is important: you're going to create a highly non-contiguous, irregular access pattern from each MPI processor.  Give the MPI-IO library a chance to optimize that request.

Also it's important to note that MPI-IO file views must be monotonically non-decreasing, so you'll have to sort the items locally before writing the data out collectively.  Local memory operations have an insignificant cost relative to an I/O operation, so this usually isn't a big deal.